# Android ICS Tutorials & Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

so I wanted to implement tab views on my app.
But I realised the google tutorial on tab views is broken and TabActivity is deprecated.
I tried inserting the tabhost element through the Graphical Layout but it won't even show up when my app starts.

It's just a blank screen.
What am I supposed to do/look for? I'm kind of lost here.
Thank you for any help/input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from its [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html), TabActivity has been replaced with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). Here's a [sample project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html).